# How can a a ratio of $\kappa/\lambda$ remain constant as $\kappa$ goes to infinity?

Tags: limits, statistics, poisson-distribution

p(y)=$\frac{\Gamma(y+\kappa)}{y!\Gamma(\kappa))}\frac{\lambda^\kappa}{(1+\lambda)^{y+\kappa}}$

I want to show that as $\kappa->\infty$ with $\mu=\kappa/\lambda$ held constant that p(y) converges to the probability mass funciton of the Poisson($\mu$).

But what does $\mu=\kappa/\lambda$ held constant mean? Does it mean that as $\kappa->\infty$ that $\lambda$ will also increase so that the ratio $\kappa/\lambda$ will always be constant?

Otherwise, as $\kappa->infty$ $\mu$ must also increase right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saying $\mu=\frac \kappa \lambda$ is constant means $\lambda$ increases too.  You can just substitute $\frac \kappa \mu$ for $\lambda$, then let $\kappa \to \infty$

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to show that p(y) converges to Poisson($\mu$)? The gamma functions aren't canceling and I can't get an exponential(-y) anywhere.

Comment: I did this a long time ago.  As I recall I applied Stirling's approximation to the gamma functions and it all came out all right.